# how to run process in shell without printing errors on the shell

Tags: python

I`m trying to run a process like this:

```
cmd = "qry_db -value x > /tmp/somefile"
os.popen(cmd)
```

sometimes, the qry_db returns an error, and it's ok. but I don't want the error to be printed on the shell, is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `os.popen()`. Use the `subprocess` module instead:

```
import subprocess

with open('/tmp/somefile', 'w') as tmpfile:
    subprocess.call(['qry_db', '-value', 'x'], stdout=tmpfile, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

This redirects `stderr` to `/dev/null`, effectively silencing errors. `stdout` is still redirected to your temporary file. You *may* want to pipe this instead, using [`subprocess.check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), to read the output straight into your Python script. You'd still use `stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL` to silence the error output.

`subprocess.DEVNULL` was added in Python 3.3. If you are using an earlier version of Python, use:

```
import subprocess
import os

with open('/tmp/somefile', 'w') as tmpfile, open(os.devnull) as devnull:
    subprocess.call(['qry_db', '-value', 'x'], stdout=tmpfile, stderr=devnull)
```

Comment: I`m getting an invalid syntax error at this line: `with open('/tmp/somefile', 'w') as tmpfile, open(os.devnull) as devnull:`

Comment: @user2234234: are you using Python 2.6 or older? Then you cannot use multiple context managers with one `with` line. Use nested `with` statements in that case: `with open(...) as tmpfile:` (indent next line) `with open(os.devnull) as devnull:` (indent again).

Answer (score 0):

write this in the beginning of your program.

```
import sys

sys.stderr = open('error.log', 'w')
```

this will write all your errors to the file `error.log`.

or if you don't want to log the error at all, on a Unix system, use the file `/dev/null`

```
sys.stderr = open('error.log', 'w')
```

Similary you can send all the output away from the terminal by using `sys.stdout`